# Angular 2: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent

Tags: angular, systemjs

From this [tutorial](http://blog.brecht.io/Modals-in-angular2/) , I'm trying to make a dynamic modal.

But I don't know what I was missing after seperate source code into files.

Please help me to take a look at: https://plnkr.co/edit/yz7gmBDirrQ6vWkWiZv0?p=preview

```
Error: (SystemJS) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import {ModalService} from "./modal.module";
```

should be

```
import {ModalService} from "./modal.service";
```

Comment: Many thanks. I just forgot to correct path after change files.